# Compute $\int_C\frac{1}{(z^2+a^2)\sin πz}dz$ where $C=\{z\in \mathbb C : |z|=N+\frac{1}{2}\}$ with $N>a>0$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z):=\frac{1}{(z^2+a^2)\sin πz}$ where $a>0$ is a constant real number.
Then, how can I calculate
$$\int_C f(z) dz$$
with contour $C:=\{z\in \mathbb C : |z|=N+\frac{1}{2}\}$, with $N>a, N\in \mathbb N$

**My attempts:**
I tried to use residue theorem so I calculated its singularities i.e. $\{+ia, -ia, n : n\in \mathbb Z\}$ but it's too complicated for me to calculate all the residues. I also got the integral with contour which contains only $z=0$, then I used Cauchy's formula, and it was
$$\int_C^{} f(z) dz=2πi*g(0)=\frac{2i}{a^2}$$
where $g(z):=\frac{z}{f(z)}$.

And I got the residues at $z\in \mathbb Z$, they are 
$$- \frac{1}{π(a^2+z^2)}$$

What can I do from here? I appreciate any help, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First note that $C$ is a circle radius $N+\frac{1}{2}$ that encloses $\pm ia$ and $-N,-N+1,\dotsc,N-1,N$, all of which are simple roots of
$$f(z) = \frac{1}{(z^2+a^2)\sin (\pi z)}$$

We may compute the residue of a simple pole $c$ using $\mathrm{Res}(f,c) = \lim_{z\to c}(z-c)f(z)$.

\begin{align}
\mathrm{Res}(f,\pm ia) &= \lim_{z\to \pm ia} \frac{(z-\pm ia)}{(z^2+a^2)\sin (\pi z)}
= \lim_{z\to \pm ia} \frac{1}{(z\pm ia)\sin(\pi z)}\\
&= \frac{1}{\pm 2i a \sin(\pm i a \pi)}
= -\frac{1}{2a\sinh(a \pi)}
\end{align}

Note that 
$$\sin(\pi(z-n)) = \sin(\pi z)\underbrace{\cos(\pi n)}_{=\,(-1)^n} - \underbrace{\sin(\pi n)}_{=\, 0}\cos(\pi z) = (-1)^n\sin(\pi z)$$
we then compute
\begin{align}
\mathrm{Res}(f, n) &= \lim_{z\to n} \frac{(z-n)}{(z^2+a^2)\sin (\pi z)}
= \frac{1}{n^2+a^2} \cdot \left[\lim_{z\to n} \frac{\sin(\pi z)}{z-n}\right]^{-1}\\
&= \frac{(-1)^n / \pi}{n^2+a^2} \cdot \left[\lim_{z\to n} \frac{\sin(\pi (z-n))}{\pi(z-n)}\right]^{-1}\\
&= \frac{(-1)^n / \pi}{n^2+a^2} \cdot \underbrace{\left[\lim_{z\to 0} \frac{\sin z}{z}\right]^{-1}}_{=\,1}
= \frac{(-1)^n / \pi}{n^2+a^2}
\end{align}

The residue theorem then gives
\begin{align}
 \int_c f(z) \,dz
&= 2\pi i \sum \mathrm{Res}(f,a_k)\\
&= 2\pi i\cdot \mathrm{Res}(f,ia)
+ 2\pi i \cdot\mathrm{Res}(f,-ia)
+ 2\pi i \sum_{n=-N}^{N} \mathrm{Res}(f,n)\\
&= -\frac{2\pi i}{a \sinh(a\pi)} + \sum_{n=-N}^{N} (-1)^n \frac{2 i}{n^2+a^2}
\end{align}